# Docker With DataStax Connection Not Working

Tags: cassandra, docker-compose, datastax-enterprise

I wrote `docker-compose.yml` file which download the image from docker store. I had already subscribe that image in docker store and I am able to pull that image. Following are the services I am using on my compose file.

- store/datastax/dse-server:5.1.6
- datastax/dse-studio

The link which I followed to write the compose file is [datastax/docker-images](https://github.com/datastax/docker-images)

I am running docker from `Docker Toolbox` because I am using Window 7.

```
version: '2'
services:
  seed_node:
    image: "store/datastax/dse-server:5.1.6"
    environment:
      - DS_LICENSE=accept
    # Allow DSE to lock memory with mlock
    cap_add:
    - IPC_LOCK
    ulimits:
      memlock: -1
  node:
    image: "store/datastax/dse-server:5.1.6"
    environment:
      - DS_LICENSE=accept
      - SEEDS=seed_node
    links:
      - seed_node
    # Allow DSE to lock memory with mlock
    cap_add:
    - IPC_LOCK
    ulimits:
        memlock: -1
  studio:
    image: "datastax/dse-studio"
    environment:
      - DS_LICENSE=accept
    ports:
      - 9091:9091
```

When I go the browser link for `http://192.168.99.100:9091/` and try to have a connection I am getting the following errors:

```
 TEST FAILED
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.99.100:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/192.168.99.100:9042] Cannot connect))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker Compose [creates a default internal network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) where all your containers get IP addresses and can communicate. The IP address you're using there (`192.168.99.100`) is the address of your **host** that's running the containers, not the internal IP addresses where the containers can communicate with each other on that default internal network. Port `9091` where you're running Studio is available on that external IP address because you exposed it in the `studio` service of your `yaml`:

```
ports:
- 9091:9091
```

For Studio to make a connection to one of your nodes, you need to be using an IP on that internal network where they communicate, not on that external IP. The cool thing with Docker Compose is that instead of trying to figure out those internal IPs, you can just use a *hostname* that matches the name of your service in the `docker-compose.yaml` file.

So to connect to the service you named `node` (i.e. the DSE node), you should just use the hostname `node` (instead of an IP) when creating the connection in Studio.